# Why are glsl variables not working as expected?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, textures

I am working on a 3D renderer which was working as expected but now I am trying to batch every cube into a single draw call (my renderer can only draw cubes right now).

Here I have my glsl program that runs for each batch

```c
#type vertex
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_Position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 a_Color;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 a_TexCoord;
layout(location = 3) in int a_TexIndex;

uniform mat4 u_ProjectionView;

out vec4 v_Color;
out vec3 v_TexCoord;
out flat int v_TexIndex;

void main()
{
    v_Color     = a_Color;
    v_TexCoord  = a_TexCoord;
    v_TexIndex  = a_TexIndex;

    gl_Position = u_ProjectionView * vec4(a_Position, 1.0);
}
```

```c
#type fragment
#version 330 core

out vec4 color;

in vec4 v_Color;
in vec3 v_TexCoord;
in flat int v_TexIndex;

uniform samplerCube u_Textures[32];

void main()
{
    color = texture(u_Textures[v_TexIndex], v_TexCoord) * v_Color;
}
```

The only part that does not work is the sampling part at the very end.

When I tested my code, I loaded two textures into the `u_Textures` array in the first two indices and tried to draw a cube with the first texture and another cube with the second texture.

If I hardcode an index like this

```c
color = texture(u_Textures[0], v_TexCoord) * v_Color;
```

Or like this

```c
color = texture(u_Textures[1], v_TexCoord) * v_Color;
```

The correct texture at index 0 or 1 is sampled but as soon as I place the `v_TexIndex` variable, it gives me weird artifacts or just nothing at all.

So I automatically thought that my `v_TexIndex` variable must not be what I expect it to be but if I replace the line with

```c
color = vec4(v_TexIndex, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

I get a white texture when I expect `v_TexIndex` to be 1 and a turquoise when I expect it to be 0!

Answer (score 4):

Arrays of samplers (`u_Textures`) cannot be indexed by fragment shader inputs such as `v_TexIndex`.
`u_Textures[v_TexIndex]` is undefined behavior, because `v_TexIndex` is not [Dynamically uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Dynamically_uniform_expression).

See GLSL version 4.60 (most recent) (from [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 4.1.7. Opaque Types](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#opaque-types)):

> When aggregated into arrays within a shader, these types can only be indexed with a dynamically uniform expression, or **texture lookup will result in undefined values**.

In the GLSL version 330, the restriction is even harder. See [OpenGL Shading Language 3.30 Specification - 4.1.7 Samplers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.3.30.pdf#page=27&zoom=100,153,586):

> Samplers aggregated into arrays within a shader (using square brackets [ ]) can only be indexed with integral constant expressions.

That clearly explains why the *"hardcode"* index (`u_Textures[0]`, `u_Textures[1]`) works, but `u_Textures[v_TexIndex]` fails and gives *"weird artifacts"*.

I recommend to use s `samplerCubeArray` (see [Sampler](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL))) rather than an array of `samplerCube`.
When you use a `samplerCubeArray`, then you don't need any indexing at all, because  the "index" is encoded in the 4rd component of the texture coordinate at texture lookup (see [`texture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texture.xhtml)).

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the links that you put in the answer and I did not completely understand how to use samplerCubeArray's; however, I have found a "hack" around my problem and it is by passing the index as a floating point value into the shader program and then texturing like this

`color = texture(u_Textures[int(v_TexIndex + 0.5)], v_TexCoord) * v_Color;`